# [Emulator]could not get wglgetextensionsstringarb

Tags: android, eclipse

When I am trying to run my emulator, it says

```
could not get wglgetextensionsstringarb
```

I have searched many links for the solution and finally I read somewhere that I have to select INTEL x86 in CPU/ABI option.  When I looked into edit option, I didn't find any option in CPU/ABI.

[image]

Comment: if that is so, you have to install the image for INTEL, just go to your SDK Manager and find the respective image, check that and download the package ... now create emulator and see